# .NET and Dynamic Languages

Tags: .net, dynamic-languages

When Microsoft gets around to releasing the DLR and related languages are you planning on utilising those languages (such as Iron Ruby or Iron Python)?

If so, what are your motivations for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in some cases.

Main motivation is to reuse existing code and libraries already implemented in Ruby and Python with easier interaction with other code written in C#. For me, its all about the cross-language integration benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  I'm certainly planning to find some non-essential project to acquaint myself with IronRuby.

I'm sure there are real projects that will benefit form using a dynamic language but I don't believe I can properly judge that until I've written some meaningful code in the language, so I think it takes a conscious effort to break the chicken and egg  situation.

I think IronRuby will provide the chance to concentrate on what's new in the language w/o being distracted by the difference of new development environment (I'm pretty much a C# monoglot).

I was waching [IronRuby: The Right Language for the Right Job](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL44/) yesterday so that might be affecting my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I plan on using them if they are right for the project I am working on.  If the project is just as easily done in C#, I will probably stick to the static language, given that the `dynamic` keyword is going to allow much of the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a .NET developer, but I'd use it considering the following conditions:

- Speed/Memory consumption (in relation to other implementations);
- Portability (or: "Is it still Python/Ruby/etc? Will this same code run on the official implementation?");
- Nice extra features (as long as they don't break too much of item 2).

Answer (score 1):

Most of these languages can be hosted with in your application, and that's the interesting point.

If you are writing an application that allows your users to write scripts for extensibility, then you should consider using them.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly intend to look at [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/). Equally I think it'd be negligent of me not to at least look at Rails and Django.

Answer (score -1):

No. Apart from some metaprogramming (Reflection sucks), dynamic languages don't really hold any appeal over statically typed languages with good type inference.

And the loss in productivity due to weak IDEs, for one, hurts quite a bit.